# Changing text color via function

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, colors

I have been trying to change the text color via one that was input and thrown into a function, but I have no clue where I am going wrong. I have used reference code and changed a value or two around, so I assume I messed something up. Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
<form>
    <input id="newColor" type="text"> <button value="Text" onclick="changeText(tColor)">Text</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="divTag"> 
THIS TEXT HERE
</div>
<script>
    function changeText(tColor) 
    {
        document.getElementById("newColor").value = tColor.value;
        document.getElementById("divTag").style.backgroundColor = tColor;
     }
 </script>
```

This is really troubling me. I also need to change the page background color but since it's in the same manner I could just learn based off of this code. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: … use `color` instead of `backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your function above the function call and wrap single quotes around tColor

Try this as well

```
   <head>
   <script type="application/javascript">
      function changeColor(x,y){
          var z = document.getElementById(y);
          z.style.color = x;
      }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button id="button_1" onclick="changeColor('red','h1')">ChangeColor</button>
   <span id="h1" style="color:blue;">Hello</span>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about tColor. But as an example if you want to change the text color to red then what you should do is as follows.

```
    <script>
          function changeText(tColor) 
          {
            document.getElementById("newColor").style.color = tColor;
            document.getElementById("divTag").style.backgroundColor = tColor;
          }
       </script>
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
       <input id="newColor" type="text"> <button value="Text" onclick="changeText('red')">Text</button>
   </form>
   <br>
   <div id="divTag"> 
    THIS TEXT HERE
   </div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nadsa/kzt5u/)
If you want to get the color from 'newColor' textbox, code should change as follows.

```
   <script>
      function changeText() 
      {
        var sColor = document.getElementById('newColor').value;
        document.getElementById("newColor").style.color = sColor;
        document.getElementById("divTag").style.backgroundColor = sColor;
      }
   </script>
```

Hope you got the answer..

Answer (score 0):

This will fix you up:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['color'])){
        if($_POST['color'] != ""){
            $color = $_POST['color'];   // be sure and sanitize this
            echo $color;
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "error";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
            var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open( meth, url, true );
            x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return x;
        }
        function ajaxReturn(x){
            if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function _(x) {
            return document.getElementById(x);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function changeColor() {
            var color = _("newColor").value;
            if (color == ""){

            } else {
                var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>");
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                        if(ajax.responseText == "error") {

                        } else {
                            var newColor = ajax.responseText;
                            var ele = _("divTag");
                            ele.style.color = newColor;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ajax.send("color="+color);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <input id="newColor" type="text">
        <button value="Text" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="divTag">THIS TEXT HERE</div>
</body>
</html>
```